# Recognize a decryption algorithm

Tags: disassembly, malware, decryption

I'm trying to reverse a malware that builds its IAT at runtime. Due to my inexperience, I'm having trouble to understand this function that accepts into EAX a dword (maybe some sort of hash) and into EDX the base address of kernel32.dll. Could you point me how can I work it out? I can't use the decompiler right now.

[image: DecryptionFunction]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function parses the PE header to locate the [`IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#export-directory-table) which has the structure

[image]

`NumberOfNames` contains the number of symbols exported by this PE and is located at an offset of `0x18`.

`AddressOfNames` is a pointer to an array of null-separated list of exported function names. This is located at offset `0x20`.

Using the `NumberOfNames` value it iterates over the list of exported function names and calculates a hash value for each.

The algorithm to calculate hash is something like.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // The name to hash
    char name[] = "GetModuleFileNameA";

    unsigned int hash = 0;
    unsigned char ch, cl;

    for (int i=0; i<strlen(name); i++)
    {
        ch = ((hash >> 8) & 0xFF) ^ name[i];
        hash = (hash & 0xffff00ff) | (ch << 8);
        hash = _rotl(hash, 8);        
        cl =  (hash & 0xFF) ^ ((hash >> 8) & 0xFF);
        hash = (hash & 0xFFFFFF00) | cl;
    }
    printf("%08X", hash);
}
```

If the calculated hash matches, it returns the corresponding address of the API.

The above code calculates the hash of `GetModuleFileNameA` which comes out to `416F346F`. The code can thus be assumed to be correct.

Check here: https://rextester.com/NIBW6473

Comment: This 0x416F346F could be the hash for GetModuleFileNameA. Or this 0x0A7E6B43 could be the hash for VirtualAlloc and this 0x65233F5A could be for Sleep.

Comment: @Kartone The code works for the given hashes.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for your help. Last question, do you know if symbol _IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY is working into Win7 and over? Actually I'm following your hints but, different from other structures, WinDBG complain there is no symbol associated. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kartone Yes, `_IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` is defined in the PE specification and would work across all Windows OS. Probably you don't have the proper pdb symbols loaded in windbg.

Comment: I will dig into the issue, then. Thanks.

Comment: @Kartone Just checked `dt _IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` on a Windows 7 box with notepad loaded in Windbg. It does work. Probably you don't have the PDB path set. Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-path#using-a-symbol-server).

Comment: some typeinfo were shifted from ntdll,ole32 to combase  try dt combase!_IMAGE_XXX   and 0x78 is pertinent for 32 bit _IMAGE_NT_HEADERS only  on x64 _IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 has been widened to accommodate 64 bit pointers so DATADIRECTORY[0] is at 0x88